# Databricks Connect : Which specified path the system cannot find?

Tags: python, pyspark, pycharm, databricks, databricks-connect

I have the following set up in my company, and I like to use databrick on my windows machine with Pycharm

- I have a databrick cluster as shown below version 7.3
- Java 8
- Spark in C drive on this path `C:\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2`
  (but I unset it from SPARK_HOME environment variable)
- PyCharm installed
- Conda installed
- pip install -U databricks-connect==7.* (based on run time version that I see in the figure below)
- following  configuration information:
  cluster URL, cluster id, organization ID, databricks token
- I dont know the port number but I am keeping default 15001
  [image: Fig 1]

Then I use the following command to make the configuration

```
databricks-connect configure
```

and then

```
databricks-connect test
```

[image]

Not working, and pauses here with

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I dont know what path I am missing

I played with SPARK_HOME variable, and was throwing following errors which was asking me to unset it.

[image]

[image]

following instructions were followed [[1]](https://medium.com/@manju.sharan797/integrating-databricks-with-pycharm-ide-968d273d48d4) [[2]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/) [[3]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-connect)

Comment: Did you run `databricks-connect test` from your dbconnect environment? (As it seems to me it fails at the python command). As for `SPARK_HOME`, do not install `pyspark` separately as this will indeed conflict. You should only install `databricks-connect` (which contains `pyspark`)

Comment: @Jyr I ran `databricks-connect test` in terminal of project. Is it wrong? If yes how do I get into `dbconnect environment` and run the `databricks-connect test` ?

Comment: conda activate dbconnect, but Pycharm should do this automatically.

Comment: @Jyr I am already in Pycharm terminal :| All of above are in Pycharm terminal